# messagebox: can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I've got a problem with tkinter saying :***"can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed"***, though I only used 2 lines of code with it creating a messagebox:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
launch = messagebox.showinfo("oops", "No such state", icon="warning")
```

the code looks like this:

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from score import Score
import pandas
from tkinter import messagebox
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.penup()
turtle.hideturtle()
writer = Turtle()
writer.hideturtle()
writer.penup()
screen = turtle.Screen()

def button():
    butt = Turtle()
    butt.penup()
    butt.hideturtle()
    butt.speed("fastest")
    butt.color(66, 184, 213)
    butt.goto(-80, -50)
    butt.pendown()
    butt.fillcolor(241, 218, 160)
    butt.begin_fill()
    butt.forward(160)
    butt.left(90)
    butt.forward(80)
    butt.left(90)
    butt.forward(160)
    butt.left(90)
    butt.forward(80)
    butt.end_fill()
    butt.penup()
    butt.goto(-65, -25)
    butt.pendown()
    butt.write(arg="Start Game", move=False, font=("Times New Roman", 30, "normal"))

button()

def game():

    screen.clear()
    screen.title = ("U.S. States Game")
    image = "blank_states_img.gif"
    screen.addshape(image)
    turtle.shape(image)
    score = Score()

    # this is to setup the right size of the screen
    # bcos turtle.screensize didn't really work..

    turtle.setup(730, 500)


    in_d = "50_states.csv"

    data = pandas.read_csv(in_d)

    guessed_states = []

    state = []
    xcor = []
    ycor = []

    num_of_states = len(data['state'])

    for i in (data["state"]):
        state.append(i)

    for i in (data["y"]):
        ycor.append(i)

    for i in (data["x"]):
        xcor.append(i)

    while score < 50:
        answer_state = screen.textinput(title='Guess the state', prompt="What's the state's name?").capitalize()

        if answer_state not in state and answer_state in guessed_states:
            launch = messagebox.showinfo("oops", "You already guessed it!", icon="warning")

        elif answer_state not in state:
            launch = messagebox.showinfo("oops", "No such state", icon="warning")

        for i in state:
            if i == answer_state:
                position = state.index(answer_state)
                x_cor = int(xcor[position])
                y_cor = int(ycor[position])
                location = (x_cor, y_cor)
                writer.goto(location)
                writer.write(arg=answer_state, move=False, font=("Times New Roman", 10, "normal"))
                score.increase_score()
                state.remove(answer_state)
                guessed_states.append(answer_state)

def butt_click(x, y):
    if x > - 50 and x < 50 and y > - 50 and y < 65:
        game()

turtle.onscreenclick(butt_click, 1)
turtle.listen()
turtle.done()

screen.exitonclick()
```

I read through some solutions for the same error but none of them seems to be similar really to my case.
Would be great if someone could take a look.
Thank you :)

-----------------------Full traceback------------------------

[full traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQMQt.png)

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: I've added it, although for now the website only allows me to add it as a link.

Comment: So it looks like your traceback is referencing code that you haven't shown us in your sample.  Somewhere in your code you must be calling something like `self.destroy()` and the error is telling you that you have tried to interact with a widget that you have already destroyed.  Where is the part of your code where you are using the bind method?

Comment: @tensai the website should allow you to add it [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, I've added the entire code, but I never used self.destroy() anywhere..

Comment: I don't remember anything about the `turtle` module but I would think maybe you are destroying something you are interacting with by calling `screen.clear()`. Maybe something you only created once that you need recreated when you call the `game()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I'd say this sequence is a problem:

```
turtle.onscreenclick(butt_click, 1)
turtle.listen()
turtle.done()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Binding screen click to your function, then rebinding it to "exit" would cause your program to quit upon start.  However, the redundant `done()` derails the call to `exitonclick()` so I don't know what you're trying to achieve.  Although I don't understand your game, and don't have enough pieces to run it, I would use the following approach to implementing it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import pandas
from tkinter import messagebox

in_d = "50_states.csv"
image = "blank_states_img.gif"

def button():
    butt = Turtle()
    butt.hideturtle()
    butt.speed("fastest")
    butt.color(66, 184, 213)
    butt.penup()
    butt.goto(-80, -50)
    butt.pendown()

    butt.fillcolor(241, 218, 160)
    butt.begin_fill()
    butt.forward(160)
    butt.left(90)
    butt.forward(80)
    butt.left(90)
    butt.forward(160)
    butt.left(90)
    butt.forward(80)
    butt.end_fill()

    butt.penup()
    butt.goto(-65, -25)
    butt.pendown()
    butt.write("Start Game", font=("Times New Roman", 30, "normal"))

def game():
    screen.clear()

    turtle.shape(image)
    score = 0

    data = pandas.read_csv(in_d)

    guessed_states = []

    states = []
    xcor = []
    ycor = []

    num_of_states = len(data['state'])

    for i in data["state"]:
        states.append(i)

    for i in data["y"]:
        ycor.append(i)

    for i in data["x"]:
        xcor.append(i)

    while score < num_of_states:
        answer_state = screen.textinput(title='Guess the state', prompt="What's the state's name?").capitalize()

        if answer_state not in states and answer_state in guessed_states:
            launch = messagebox.showinfo("oops", "You already guessed it!", icon="warning")
        elif answer_state not in states:
            launch = messagebox.showinfo("oops", "No such state", icon="warning")
        else:
            position = states.index(answer_state)
            writer.goto(xcor[position], ycor[position])
            writer.write(answer_state, font=("Times New Roman", 10, "normal"))
            score += 1
            states.remove(answer_state)
            guessed_states.append(answer_state)

def butt_click(x, y):
    if -50 < x < 50 and -50 < y < 65:
        game()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.hideturtle()

writer = Turtle()
writer.hideturtle()
writer.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(730, 500)
screen.colormode(255)
screen.title = ("U.S. States Game")
screen.addshape(image)
screen.onclick(butt_click, 1)

button()

screen.mainloop()
```

You might be better off setting the window's background to the states map via `bgpic()` rather than use a turtle for the purpose.

Comment: the game per se is simple, it starts with a start button "start game", when you click on it you see the map of the US and then the prompt lets you guess the name of a State, if you guessed it, the name of the State appears on the map and the score goes up.

Comment: ok, so I checked your code line by line and deleting turtle.exitonclick() and turtle.done() replacing it with turtle.mainloop() did the trick :) thank you:)